# UIAlertView button tagging

Tags: iphone, uialertview

Is there a way I can add a .tag to an UIAlertView button? Reason being, I'm adding a few dynamic buttons to the alert that will sometimes be in the alert and sometimes not. I figured the best way was to add a tag. Is there a better method for this?

The options that will ALWAYS be in the alert are Email, Save. And the 2 optional options are Tweet This and Facebook.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one method buttonTitleAtIndex for UIAlertView. Use that to find the button tapped by user.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *buttonString = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if( [buttonString isEqualToString:@"Facebook"] ){
        // your code here
    } else if( [buttonString isEqualToString:@"twitter"] ){
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: That is PERFECT! I was going by the buttonIndex which isn't reliable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **tag** proprerty:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info"
                                                message:@"Info text"
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];   
[alert setTag:0];
```

Then in delegate:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {  
    switch (alertView.tag) {
      case 1: {
        ... 
        break;
      } 
      ...  
    default:
        break;
}
```